# Why is my published deferred Observable factory being called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a a task stream that will queue until a signal Subject is triggered using the `.zip()` operator.  The signal subject subscribes to the currently running task.  I am trying to also observe the progress emissions of the task.

What I have tried to do is use `.publish()` to multicast the task Observable so that I can allow the signal Subject to subscribe to the `.last()` emission of the task to cause a dequeue and also subscribe to the tasks general progress emissions.

This *seems* to be working.  However, whenever I look at what is printed out, it looks like my Observable factory is getting called by each `.subscribe()` call even though I used `.publish()`.  Am I misunderstanding  how multicasting works?  I believed the `.publish()`ed Observable would be created with the factory and that singular instance would be shared, but cold until `.connect()` was called.

### My Task Runner

Notice the `.defer()` that calls `tasker`.

```js
"use strict";

const {
  Observable,
  Subject,
  BehaviorSubject
} = Rx;

// How often to increase project in a task
const INTERVAL_TIME = 200;

// Keep track of how many tasks we have
let TASK_ID = 0;

// Easy way to print out observers
function easyObserver(prefix = "Observer") {
  return {
    next: data => console.log(`[${prefix}][next]: ${data}`),
    error: err => console.error(`[${prefix}][error] ${err}`),
    complete: () => console.log(`[${prefix}][complete] Complete`)
  };
}

// Simulate async task
function tasker(name = "", id = TASK_ID++) {
  console.log(`tasker called for ${id}`);

  let progress = 0;
  const progress$ = new BehaviorSubject(`Task[${name||id}][${progress}%]`);
  console.log(`Task[${name||id}][started]`);
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    progress = (progress + (Math.random() * 50));
    if (progress >= 100) {
      progress = 100;
      clearInterval(interval);
      progress$.next(`Task[${name||id}][${progress}%]`);
      progress$.complete();
      return;
    }
    progress$.next(`Task[${name||id}][${progress}%]`);
  }, INTERVAL_TIME);

  return progress$.asObservable();
}

// Create a signal subject that will tell the queue when to next
const dequeueSignal = new BehaviorSubject();

// Make some tasks
const tasks$ = Observable
  .range(0, 3);

// Queue tasks until signal tells us to emit the next task
const queuedTasks$ = Observable
  .zip(tasks$, dequeueSignal, (i, s) => i);

// Create task observables
const mcQueuedTasks$ = queuedTasks$
  .map(task => Observable.defer(() => tasker(`MyTask${task}`)))
  .publish();

// Print out the task progress
const progressSubscription = mcQueuedTasks$
  .switchMap(task => task)
  .subscribe(easyObserver("queuedTasks$"));

// Cause the signal subject to trigger the next task
const taskCompleteSubscription = mcQueuedTasks$
  .switchMap(task => task.last())
  .delay(500)
  .subscribe(dequeueSignal);

// Kick everything off
mcQueuedTasks$.connect();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

### My Output

Notice how you see multiple calls to tasker with the line `tasker called for N` and that the body of the factory is called.  However, before any progress emissions happen, `tasker()` is called again with the next `TASK_ID`.  The output seems correct because `Task[MyTask0]` doesn't skip any indices, only `TASK_ID`s.

```
tasker called for 0
Task[MyTask0][started]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask0][0%]
tasker called for 1
Task[MyTask0][started]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask0][20.688413934455674%]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask0][32.928520335195564%]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask0][42.58361384849108%]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask0][73.1297043008671%]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask0][100%]
tasker called for 2
Task[MyTask1][started]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask1][0%]
tasker called for 3
Task[MyTask1][started]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask1][37.16513927245511%]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask1][47.27771448102375%]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask1][60.45983311604027%]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask1][100%]
tasker called for 4
Task[MyTask2][started]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask2][0%]
tasker called for 5
Task[MyTask2][started]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask2][32.421275902708544%]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask2][41.30332084025583%]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask2][77.44113197852694%]
[queuedTasks$][next]: Task[MyTask2][100%]
[queuedTasks$][complete] Complete
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like `Observable.defer` is unnecessary in this function:

```
// Create task observables
const mcQueuedTasks$ = queuedTasks$
  .map(task => Observable.defer(() => tasker(`MyTask${task}`)))
  .publish();
```

> The Defer operator waits until an observer subscribes to it, and then
>   it generates an Observable, typically with an Observable factory
>   function. It does this afresh for each subscriber, so although each
>   subscriber may think it is subscribing to the same Observable, in fact
>   each subscriber gets its own individual sequence.

You've already created an Observable here:

```
// Make some tasks
const tasks$ = Observable
  .range(0, 3);
```

Within the `map` loop you're creating an extra Observable for each task...

Get rid of `Observable.defer` so the function would look like this:

```
// Create task observables
const mcQueuedTasks$ = queuedTasks$
 .map(task => tasker(`MyTask${task}`))
 .publish();
```

Snippet:

```js
"use strict";

const {
  Observable,
  Subject,
  BehaviorSubject
} = Rx;

// How often to increase project in a task
const INTERVAL_TIME = 200;

// Keep track of how many tasks we have
let TASK_ID = 0;

// Easy way to print out observers
function easyObserver(prefix = "Observer") {
  return {
    next: data => console.log(`[${prefix}][next]: ${data}`),
    error: err => console.error(`[${prefix}][error] ${err}`),
    complete: () => console.log(`[${prefix}][complete] Complete`)
  };
}

// Simulate async task
function tasker(name = "", id = TASK_ID++) {
  console.log(`tasker called for ${id}`);

  let progress = 0;
  const progress$ = new BehaviorSubject(`Task[${name||id}][${progress}%]`);
  console.log(`Task[${name||id}][started]`);
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    progress = (progress + (Math.random() * 50));
    if (progress >= 100) {
      progress = 100;
      clearInterval(interval);
      progress$.next(`Task[${name||id}][${progress}%]`);
      progress$.complete();
      return;
    }
    progress$.next(`Task[${name||id}][${progress}%]`);
  }, INTERVAL_TIME);

  return progress$.asObservable();
}

// Create a signal subject that will tell the queue when to next
const dequeueSignal = new BehaviorSubject();

// Make some tasks
const tasks$ = Observable
  .range(0, 3);

// Queue tasks until signal tells us to emit the next task
const queuedTasks$ = Observable
  .zip(tasks$, dequeueSignal, (i, s) => i);

// Create task observables
const mcQueuedTasks$ = queuedTasks$
  .map(task => tasker(`MyTask${task}`))
  .publish();

// Print out the task progress
const progressSubscription = mcQueuedTasks$
  .switchMap(task => task)
  .subscribe(easyObserver("queuedTasks$"));

// Cause the signal subject to trigger the next task
const taskCompleteSubscription = mcQueuedTasks$
  .switchMap(task => task.last())
  .delay(500)
  .subscribe(dequeueSignal);

// Kick everything off
mcQueuedTasks$.connect();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Working as expected, but can you explain the difference it made? Why always 2 instances were running concurrently

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure I understand why this is different.  I thought that the `defer` would have worked the same or had the same outcome if I had put it in the `map` or not.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, You don't need `defer` at all. I've corrected my answer with more details.